# SimpleDateFormat Converting String to date

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, simpledateformat

I want to insert the date in a customer table in Oracle database.
I have tow attributes `id NUMBER(8)` and `dtRt Date`

```
 //entity
 @ Column (name = "DT_RT")
 @ Temporal (TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date dtRt;
```

when converting

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd / MM / yyyy");
 date = formatter.parse (jFormattedTextField1.getText ());
```

I get:

```
Fri Mar 30 00:00:00 CET 14
```

but when I inserted into the table, the date is not inserted.

```
//DAO
public void add(Employe e)
{   
    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
    et.begin();
    em.persist(e);
    et.commit();  
}
```

// method on application client

```
public  void add(int mat,String grade,String fonction, int cnprs,int cin,String np   ,String adress,String tel,int disp,Date date)
{
   Employe emp=new Employe();
   Grade  gr=  bean.grade_emp(grade);
   Fonction  f=  bean.fonction_emp(fonction);
   emp.setMatEmp(mat);
   emp.setNumGrd(gr.getNumGrd());
   emp.setNumFon(f.getNumFon());
   emp.setCnprs(cnprs);
   emp.setCin(cin);
   emp.setAdress(adress);
   emp.setTel(tel);
   emp.setNp(np);
   emp.setDispo(disp);
   bean.add(emp);
}
```

Comment: Please show the (essential) code you're using to attempt the insert.

Comment: public void add(Employe e)
   {   EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
       et.begin();
       em.persist(e);
       et.commit();
       
   }

Comment: i think i must converter Date i can't insert Fri Mar 30 00:00:00 CET 14  to date

Comment: You should edit your question and post your code there, not post it as a comment.

Comment: yeah sorry it okay now i think i have prb when converting  date

Comment: _but when I inserted into the table, the date is not inserted._: Could you explain on what happens? do you get an exception? Is an incorrect date inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is simple: you never set the date of the employee in the `add()` method. The `date` argument of the method is ignored.